# Laravel 6 database relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am not really good on this subject.

I have two tables. Buyers and Trackers.

In trackers table I have these columns

```
id, buyer_id, style_name
```

and the buyer table is

```
id, buyer_name
```

When I retrieve and display trackers list I want to be able display buyer_name as well.

in my Buyer.php model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tracker extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *  
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'trackers';

    protected $fillable = [
        'buyer_id',
        'style_name',
    ];

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Buyer');
    }
}
```

I use artisan tinker to test. so, code is;

```
$tracker = Tracker::find(1)->buyer;
```

but I get this error

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'buyers.tracker_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `buyers` where `buyers`.`tracker_id` = 1 and `buyers`.`tracker_id` is not null limit 1)'
```

Its looking for a tracker_id in buyers table but I just one to retrieve using its id. What am I doing wrong?

this is the migration file of trackers

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pattern_room_trackers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('buyer_id');
        $table->string('style_name');

        $table->foreign('buyer_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('buyers')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

I also don't know how to display this in my blade view.

TrackerController.php

```
 public function index()
 {
   $trackers = Tracker::latest()->paginate(5);
   return view('trackers.index',compact('trackers'))
    ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
  }
```

index.blade.php

```
      @foreach ($trackers as $tracker)
      <tr>
          <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
          <td>{{ $tracker->style_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $tracker->buyer_name }}</td>
      </tr>
       @endforeach
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need yo use `belongsTo` relationship. Buyer is parent of Tracker.

```
public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Buyer','buyer_id');
    }
```

and in blade

```
<td>{{ $tracker->buyer->buyer_name }}</td>
```

read the laravel doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) about one to many inverse relationship.

Comment: Thank you. I red the doc but it's too confusing for me. Trying to learn. It's now working. Thanks again.